# Can't install modules? "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named Cython"

Tags: python, pandas

I have just installed python 3.8 and am using pycharm community edition as an interface. This has not happened previously, but when I install "pandas" module i receive the following error:

Executed command: 
`pip install pandas`

```sh
"Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe'.

File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 721, in fetch_build_eggs
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 791, in fetch_build_egg
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-av09bwyr\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 450, in <module>

      File "C:\Users\SMafl\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-av09bwyr\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 433, in setup_package
        def finalize_options(self):
      File "C:\Users\SMafl\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-av09bwyr\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 240, in generate_cython
        """Custom distutils command to clean the .so and .pyc files."""
    RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SMafl\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pandas\
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error traceback?

Comment: Have Edited above

Comment: do you have Cython installed? (`pip3 install Cython`)

Comment: I have tried this and cmd returns: 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: try using `pip` instead of `pip3`. The latter one is actually just an alias specific to Python3, important when you have both 2 and 3 installed.

Comment: It just returns the same message!